# SVG Rect Fill Issue

Tags: svg

Why isn’t the SVG rectangle fill property not extending the height of the rectangle?  I can get it fill with the height property in the SVG tag, but then lose the ability to dynamically scale the rectangle. The browser image is from Firefox. Thanks in advance!

[Browser pictured of the fill issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icFbv.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Test SVG Size</title>
</head>
<body>

  <svg
      version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

        <rect fill="green" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="200"></rect>
        <rect fill="yellow" x="100" y="0" width="100" height="200"></rect>
        <rect fill="red" x="200" y="0" width="100" height="200"></rect>


  </svg>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a viewBox attribute to your SVG.  The total width of the 3 rectangles in your svg is 300 user units and the height is 200. In this case `viewBox="0 0 300 200"`

```html
  <svg viewBox="0 0 300 200"
      version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

        <rect fill="green" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="200"></rect>
        <rect fill="yellow" x="100" y="0" width="100" height="200"></rect>
        <rect fill="red" x="200" y="0" width="100" height="200"></rect>


  </svg>
```

Comment: You are right that can be accomplished by using a viewbox, but the viewbox is just adding a height measurement to the svg. viewBox = <min-x> <min-y> <width> <height>  -   Wondering, why it show the proper width of the rectangle, but not the proper height of the rectangle.

Comment: Since you were partly right, I'm going to give you the right answer mark. The real reason that it was only showing first 150px is because the SVG viewbox defaults to a height of 150px, if the viewbox is omitted. [link]( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/height)